# Encryption is changing my JSON format

Tags: json, encryption, aes

I am encrypting my JSON file using AES. The encryption is working fine. But, after encryption the format is getting changed (not sure to what) due to which the existing code is breaking. Is there any way to confirm whether the encrypted data is in JSON format? If yes,how to do that?

Please let me know if any more detail is required.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us both case : Encrypted and decrypted

Comment: Decrypt into a string or something and perform a comparison. If you are using an IDE, you can try the debugging feature available in it. That would save the trouble of decrypting and comparison. You will need a human eye validation of the original plaintext and the decrypted plaintext.

Comment: Provide examples of both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to confirm whether the encrypted data is in JSON format?

Without providing any more information we don't know what you do with the source json.

Encrypted data are always byte stream (or byte array). If you encode and format encrypted values, it's really up to you